# A doubt regarding probabilities of a entangled states?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

Given an state of entangled particle pair in Horizontal-Vertical basis ($H,V$):

$ \psi_{hybrid}= (1/\sqrt2) (HH+VV)$

Let us define a new Right-Left basis ($R,L$) as follows:

- $L=(1/\sqrt2)(H-iV)$
- $R=(1/\sqrt2)(H+iV)$

The above equation can be re-written as:

$ \psi_{hybrid}= (1/2) [(H+iV)L + (H-iV)R]$

**Doubt 1:** Am I correct to interpret that strictly based on this above equation can be interpreted as either the pair are in the state: $(H+iV)L$ or $(H-iV)R$ ? I am guessing so but still need confirmation.

**Doubt 2:** If the assumption in doubt 1 is correct then the sum of probabilities of the above hybrid state must also be equal to 1 but as I see the sum of the amplitudes of this mixed basis state is: $(1/2)^2 + (1/2)^2 = 1/2$. But that does not seem correct as the proababiltes don't add up to 1.

What am I interpreting wrong here in the above 2 statements?

P.S. My background is not in physics but CS and I am just starting in QC. Thus please take that in to consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubt 1 is fine, up to the normalisation identified below.

Doubt 2: The pair are either in the state $\frac{H+iV}{\sqrt{2}}L$ or $\frac{H-iV}{\sqrt{2}}R$ (each output needs to be correctly normalised). So, each of these possibilities has an amplitude $1/\sqrt{2}$, and hence probability $\frac12$.

The fact that there is an overall factor of $\frac12$ in the way you wrote it out means that if you measured the first qubit in the H/V basis and the second in the L/R basis, there would be 4 possible results, each with amplitude $\frac12$ and hence probability $\frac14$. So it all adds up correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please explain the process of normalization for the generic state: $\psi_{hybrid}= [a(H+iV)L + b(H-iV)R]$ where $a$ and $b$ are some complex/real numbers such that the normalized state is in the form $\psi_{hybrid}= [a'(H+iV)L + b'(H-iV)R]$ where $(a')^2+(b')^2=1$ (I think that is what normalization means?)

Comment: To explain this properly is an answer to a different question. Please ask it!